# While loop with beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

Alright. Now I am really stumped. I am scraping data with beautiful soup and the pages have a structured format such as the link is `https://www.brightscope.com/ratings/a` the ratings go through `other`. Each letter, such as a, b, c, ..., after ratings has multiple pages for them. I am trying to create a while loop to go to each page and while a certain condition exists scrape all the hrefs (which I haven't gotten to that code yet). However, when I run the code the while loop continues to run non stop. How can I fix it to go to each page and search for a condition to run then if it isn't found go to the next letter? Before any might ask, I have searched the code and don't see any `li` tags while it continues to run.

For instance: `https://www.brightscope.com/ratings/A/18` is the highest it will go for the A's but it keeps running.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
hrefs = []
ratings = []
ks = []
pages_scrape = []

for href in soup.findAll('a'):
    if 'href' in href.attrs:
        hrefs.append(href.attrs['href'])
for good_ratings in hrefs:
    if good_ratings.startswith('/ratings/'):
        ratings.append(url[:-9]+good_ratings)

del ratings[0]
del ratings[27:]
count = 1
# So it runs each letter a, b, c, ... 
for each_rating in ratings:
    #Pulls the page
    page = requests.get(each_rating)
    #Does its soup thing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    #Supposed to stay in A, B, C,... until it can't find the 'li' tag
    while soup.find('li'):
        page = requests.get(each_rating+str(count))
        print(page.url)
        count = count+1
        #Keeps running this and never breaks
    else:
        count = 1
        break
```

Comment: Each time you evaluate `soup.find('li')`, `soup` is the same as it was last time, so it's going to find the same `li` tag, over and over again forever.

Comment: The condition `soup.find('li')` never becomes false because the variable `soup` never changes in the loop. Add line `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')` after `count = count+1`.

Comment: Maybe you wanted something like `for _ in soup.find_all('li'):`? Or, alternatively, you could store the results of `soup.find('li')` in a variable so the next time through you could ask for an `li` that's a sibling of the last li, or something like that, but that seems more complicated.

Comment: @DYZ Why would reparsing the same page again help anything?

Comment: @abarnert It is not the same page.

Comment: I don’t like how I have the code right now going to the page then going right back to scrape it

Comment: as said above `while soup.find('li')` will run forever. Moreover, there are 285 li tags in your page, not 18, if you are looking for some specific `li` you should filter more.

Answer (score 1):

BeautfulSoup's [`find()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup.find) method finds first child. That means, if you need to go through all `<li>` elements you need to use findAll() method and iterate over its result.

Answer (score 0):

The `soup.find('li')` is never being changed. All you do in the while loop is update the variable `page` and `count`. You need to make a new soup with the `page` variable, then it will change. Maybe something like this

```
while soup.find('li'):
        page = requests.get(each_rating+str(count))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        print(page.url)
        count = count+1
        #Keeps running this and never breaks
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do but maybe something like this. I edited original comment